# How to us a base class in an output parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, output-parameter

Say I have code like this:

```
class B {}
class D : class B {}

void MakeD(int params, D** out, int* status_out);
```

Today I call it like this:

```
B* b;
if (use_d) {
  D* d;
  MakeD(params, &d, &status)
  b = d;
} else...
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this avoiding a separate 'd' object, but without losing the existing type safety (i.e. no reinterpret_cast)?

Comment: Instead of using an "out" argument, why not simply return the pointer?

Comment: I cannot see any `D` object instantiation here. You are working with undefined pointers. What's happening inside MakeD?

Comment: Changing your tags. C doesn't have classes. This is C++

Comment: @evanmcdonnal http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/48401/learning-c-properly-not-c-with-classes

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Ok, I don't get the point of that. All I read was a bunch of people who probably write terrible C++ code saying how you should use all the awful features of C++ and not just classes. It made me cringe.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal exactly. In my book, the code in the question isn't C++, but C with classes. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  In my actual code the MakeD runs asynchronously, and fills in `out` at a later time, which makes the obvious "just return D*" answer impossible.  But I obviously simplified the question too much.  If anyone is still reading, is there any way to do this WITHOUT returning D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't just modify your MakeD() method to return a new D instead of passing in a pointer to a D?

ie.

```
D* MakeD(int params, int* status_out);

...

b = MakeD(params, &status);
```

Or is the MakeD() method a part of someone else's API?

Comment: In my code, the 'out' is filled in asynchronously, so I can't change MakeD to return it synchronously, but obviously that constraint wasn't formulated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use basic C++ features such as class constructor and polymorphism: `B* b = new D(params);`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
B *b = use_d ? new D(params) : new <something else>;
```

should work. I'm assuming the *something else* is probably a `B` object (constructed using different parameters maybe?). It needs to be `B` or a class derived from `B` for the code to work.

And, as always, don't use a raw `B*`, instead use

```
std::unique_ptr<B> ptr( use_d ? new D(params) : new <something else> );
```